# SQl query understanding

Tags: mysql, sql

today i am working on an SQL query and i just want get count after getting the difference as shown in my query but it is showing redundant count value.please explain this is happening?

```
select ((select count(city) from station) - (select count(distinct city) from station))
from station;
```

as when i am using distinct the problem hence solved.
so help me for a better understanding of the SQL query.

Comment: Are you asking about MySQL (where tag [tag:oracle] is not appropriate) or Oracle database (where tag [tag:mysql] is not appropriate)?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a single difference between the counts from the two subqueries, then try selecting from the `dual` table:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(city) FROM station) - (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT city) FROM station) AS diff
FROM dual;
```

But actually, you could even do this without a subquery at all:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(city) - COUNT(DISTINCT city) AS diff
FROM station;
```

Comment: what does dual keyword mean?

Comment: one more query that i have to find the length of the city name and then find largest and shortest city name in terms of length then how could i find out that in SQL ?

Comment: @AnujSingh That sounds like a great topic for another question.  But, it's not directly related to the question you asked, so I won't answer it here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are your sure your description of `DUAL` is 100% correct? As far as I know, `DUAL` in MySQL contains exactly one row (just as it does in Oracle). If if would contain no rows, `SELECT <constant_expression> FROM dual` would never return anything.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Yes, `dual` has one row, I removed my comment.  It wouldn't even be needed in MySQL, but there is nothing wrong with using it either.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach it differently, by reducing number of Select clauses.

- In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), get the counts within single Select.
- Use the result from the derived table, to compute the difference.

Try the following:

```
SELECT derived_t.total_city_count - derived_t.unique_city_count AS difference 
FROM 
(
  SELECT COUNT(city) AS total_city_count, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT city) AS unique_city_count
  FROM station
)
```